# Why does my website scroll on mobile when there is no HTML beyond the height of the screen?

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently writing an HTML website from scratch.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, when using developer tools to simulate the website, the `<body>` height is only 100% of the screen, but the website allows the user to scroll beyond the bottom of the footer.

Here is what the HTML is structured like:

```
<body onload="addNavbarFromJS()">
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Lorem impsum.</h1>
    </div>
    <footer>...</footer>
```

And here's the relevant CSS. My goal is to make the content at least as tall as the height of the screen, subtracted by the navbar and footer heights so if the content doesn't reach the bottom of the screen, it won't scroll.

```
#content {
    margin: 8vw calc(var(--text-small) * 3);
    min-height: calc(100vh - (var(--nav-text) + 64px) - calc(var(--text-small) * 8));
}

footer {
    height: calc(var(--text-small) * 3);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    font-size: var(--text-small);
}
```

Comment: this is most likely because you're using the VH unit, can you make a Codepen with your HTML so I can debug it?

Comment: Actually, I have solved it. The issue was all contained in the footer text, which had additional margins that scrolled beyond the end of the page sideways and downwards. Thank you though!

Comment: Footer deafult width is 100%. You should n't set the width by your self! Thats what caused the problem!